# How do I fix DWM "make clean install" command error?

Tags: x-dwm

I was setting up DWM window manager on debian, but when conpiling it, it came up with an error.

I installed it, then tried to run it with `make clean install`, but it did not have the `make` command.  I installed it with `sudo apt-get install -y make`.  I tried to run `make clean install`, but it came up with the error:

```
make: cc: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:18: drw.o] Error 127
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Doing just `make install` (`sudo` if required) the first time should fix the error.

As to why it happens — you probably have a custom Makefile or your `rm` binary does not understand the `-f` flag. The upstream Makefile has the following under the `clean` target:

```makefile
clean:
    rm -f dwm ${OBJ} dwm-${VERSION}.tar.gz
```

Ensure that your Makefile also passes the `-f` flag to `rm` (which means "ignore nonexistent files").